# Limit menu height in Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c++

Is there a way to set/limit the height of a menu in a windows form?

[image]

Currently, I'm having many menu items in a menu, and the menu stretches from the top of my screen to the bottom, with the scroll arrows on either side. Is there a way to make the menu shorter (i.e limit the height) and such that the scrolling arrows still show on the ends of the menu?

Comment: Of course, don't cram so many menu items in the menu :(  They just stop being useful when you force the user to scroll.  Use sub-menus.

Comment: You're right. But I'm just wondering if there's a way to achieve this without using submenu.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the maximum size of the drop down:

```
testToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.MaximumSize = new Size(200, 500);
```

However as others already mentioned I would consider this a bad UI desing. I think nobody likes to scroll through an endless list of menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the height of your menus by the simple expedient of putting fewer items in them.